# querySelector of item by a pattern of id

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get all elements with id `feed_item_{n}` where `{n}` can be any integer greater than 0.
I know that I can use `document.querySelectorAll('[id^="feed_item_"]')` but that doesn't really help because I get also elements with these ids: `feed_item_0_x`, `feed_item_x_0` where x may be any string
Is there a quick way to achieve that in one single line rather than running over all the elements I got from previous command and filttering them?

Comment: I think the only option would be to loop through an array and select each id separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's not possible to use RegEx within attribute selectors, the only way is to filter your `querySelectorAll` result; and there.. you can use a regex to match only numbers after `feed_item_`

It will be something like this

```
let items = [...document.querySelectorAll('[id^="feed_item_"]')].filter(
  (item) => item.id.match(/\d+$/)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You also can use `:not` attribute, to get items whose `id` doesn't have `_x` by `:not([id*="_x"]`

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="feed_item_"]:not([id*="_x"])')

console.log([...items])
```

```html
<div id="feed_item_1">feed_item_1</div>
<div id="feed_item_2">feed_item_2</div>
<div id="feed_item_x_1">feed_item_x_1</div>
<div id="feed_item_1_x">feed_item_1_x</div>
```

Comment: I didn't clarify in my post that 'x' can be any string, just editted the post.